# codeigniter send email working but not all the time

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, server, smtp

this is driving me crazy.... I have just uploaded a site with this email configuration for receiving message from the contact form:

```
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'mail.mysite.com',
        'smtp_port' => 587,
        'smtp_user' => 'noreply@mysite.com.ar', 
        'smtp_pass' => 'mypass', 
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
    ); 

    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from($data['ct_email'], "contact form");
    $this->email->reply_to($data['ct_email']);
    $this->email->to("prueba@mysite.com");
    $this->email->bcc("noreply@mysite.com.ar"); //copy
    $this->email->subject($data['ct_subject']);
    $this->email->message($data['ct_message']);

    $email = false; 
    if($this->email->send()){     
        $email = true;   
    } 
    return $email;
```

As you can see I have a .com and a .com.ar, My server is configured with the .com.ar account but I created an alias with the .com

The problem is that messages arrive in 1 to 10 messages sended...so that means it only works sometimes.

How can I solve this? I have tried changing email addresses but it's all the same...

I keep trying sending messages and it only send sometimes. For the ones that are not sended this is the error displayed:

-0300 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail. 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Comment: There is no logic in your code that shows "sometimes".  Read the server logs... either the server is sending every email or it isn't.  If not, there should be an error message.  If it's shared hosting, then you may need to contact the provider to see these logs.

Comment: @sparky well...it's true that it's not sending all the time the emails. check my updated question with the error

Comment: This has nothing to do with your logic.  Your error message tells you everything you need to know.  Contact your server admin to find out what they can do, if anything, to fix it.

Comment: I have already done that. I'm just waiting for their response. anyways I thought it might be something with codeigniter. It's really strange

Comment: The simple fact that you have the error message proves that CodeIgniter is composing and sending the email.

Comment: Yes, @sparky is correct, this is related to server, I think there is sending problem with authorization or you don't have permission of sending emails in bulk.

Comment: Is there anything that I can do to find a solution or it only dependes on the hosting provider?

Comment: You are at the mercy of your provider.

Comment: thnx sparky, you always reply my posts! very much appreciatted